# Android changing background color from different activity

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I'm trying to change the backgroud color of my main activity. From the menu, I select settings and brings me into another activity with settings. When I click on my checkbox to change the backgroud, it crashes. I'm trying to change the backgroud of the main activity view. LinearLayout is child of the main activity and the one I wish to change.  But I keep getting nullpointers, any help on what I can do to fix this or what do I need to do get this to work?

settings activity class:

```
public class ShowSettingsActivity extends Activity {
    static final String TAG = "CAT";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_settings_layout);

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append("\n" + sharedPrefs.getBoolean("night_mode_key", true));
        builder.append("\n" + sharedPrefs.getString("time_usage_key", "-1"));
        builder.append("\n" + sharedPrefs.getString("language_key", "-1"));

        //builder.append("\n" + sharedPrefs.getBoolean("time_history_key", true));

        TextView settingsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_text_view);
        settingsTextView.setText(builder.toString());    
    }
}
```

preference activity class:

```
public class QuickPrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    CheckBoxPreference isReg;
    static final String TAG = "QuickPrefsActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); 

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,R.xml.preferences, false);

        CheckBoxPreference  night_checkbox = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("night_mode_key");        

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Show current settings");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ShowSettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(QuickPrefsActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", 0);

        // Create a editor to edit the preferences:
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = s.edit();

        // Let's do something a preference value changes
        if (key.equals("night_mode_key")) 
        {
            // Create a reference to the checkbox (in this case):
            CheckBoxPreference mHints = (CheckBoxPreference)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("night_mode_key");

            //Lets change the summary so the user knows what will happen using a one line IF statement:
            //mHints.setSummary(mHints.isChecked() ? "Hints will popup." : "No hints will popup.");
            // Lets store the new preference:
            //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            boolean checkBoxValue = s.getBoolean("night_mode_key", false);

            if (checkBoxValue) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "true onshared" + checkBoxValue);

                //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                View v = findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
                //View root = v.getRootView();

                v.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
                /*((TextView) findViewById(R.id.hanziTextView)).setTextColor(0xff000000);
                  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView)).setTextColor(0xff000000);
                  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.instructionTextView)).setTextColor(0xff000000);*/

            }
            else
            {
            /* findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1).setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.hanziTextView)).setTextColor(0xff444444);
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView)).setTextColor(0xff444444);
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.instructionTextView)).setTextColor(0xff444444);*/
                Log.d(TAG, "false onshared" + checkBoxValue);
            }                      

            //checkBox.setChecked(false);

            editor.putBoolean("night_mode_key", mHints.isChecked());

            // Save the results:
            editor.commit();
        }

        if (key.equals("language_key")) {

            sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
           //ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) sharedPreferences; 
           String entryvalue = sharedPreferences.getString( "language_key", "");
           Log.d(TAG, "Entryvalue " + entryvalue);

            if (entryvalue.equals("EN"))
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "EN " + entryvalue);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "English Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (entryvalue.equals("CH"))
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "CH " + entryvalue);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Chinese Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You may not go where no1 has gone before, pick again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main layout xml... the one i'm trying to change background:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">        

    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/gestureOverlayView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" 
            android:layout_gravity="start">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                android:text="@string/startTime"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#666"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#333"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        />    
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to spend a few hours reading the documentation or following some tutorials (there are thousands) and try to **understand** them. From what I see I can tell you hardly know what you're doing, so it's hard to correct your code.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I didn't want to give that impression, I didn't think it was necessary to put my entire code so that's why there is little code settings area. I think conceptually i have an idea of whats wrong. I'm getting a null because I'm not in the view and I'm trying to change something in another view. I'm not sure if you could even past the view and it would work.  Thats why I'm here in forums. Anything specific you need. I would put more code if necessary.

Comment: Okay I updated with more code.

Comment: If you notice the onSharedPreferenceChanged fucntion, specifically the if (checkBoxValue) function you will see exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

It will crash because the targeted `LinearLayout` is in another activity. what you can do is.. save the color of the background or settings in a `Sharedpreferences` file.. then call it again in the main activity to change the color...

```
 if (checkBoxValue) 
         {
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor edit = sp.edit();
            edit.putString("COLOR", "0xffffffff")
         }
```

then in your main check the value of the sharedPreferences...

```
...
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
v.setBackgroundColor(sp.getString("COLOR"), Color.WHITE); // here check if the value available, if not put the color to default.. maybe white?...
```

this is untested code.. I wrote it roughly.. but I hope you got the idea.
Please give me a feedback

Comment: Will this work though if I'm coming from the main activity into this preference settings activity.  I then select the checkbox and then I use press back button on the phone, when I enter into the main activity again, do i need something to automatic refresh?  Would I need a listener inside of the main activity?

Comment: If you notice the onSharedPreferenceChanged function, specifically the if (checkBoxValue) function you will see exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can just add the sharedPreferences and setBackgroundColor in onResume not in onCreate.. in this case it will work when you start activity for first time or onBackPress

Comment: I think your right about Resume. I quickly checked from settings to main with the back button using logcat and it seems to trigger that.  I will get back to you if this worked out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the layout view of the main activity from another activity. The way to do it would be to add an extra to the intent that launches the main activity again, or you could use SharedPreferences.